# Getting error when I run Python script to open a website in Linux['Firefox']

Tags: python, linux, webdriver

Here is my **python** code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

class InstagramBot:

    def __init__(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./firefox')
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
```

**Getting this Error in Terminal** :-

raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service ./firefox unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0

> Can you provide me a working Solution/Code ?

Comment: What did use have in the executable path? Which version of selenium executable did you use?

Comment: Why are you using a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should see if the Firefox version is compatible with the Geckodriver executable and the Selenium version your using.

you can check the selenium version with: `python -c "import selenium; print(selenium.__version__)"` this will output the version number

check the Firefox version with: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/find-what-version-firefox-you-are-using

check => https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

(i'm using Ubuntu 18.04 but i think the commands are the same on different distro's)

If they are compatible, you should check if Geckodriver is in your $PATH. Open up a new terminal window and type `'whereis Geckodriver'`. The output will tell you in wich folder the executable is. (my output looks like this => `'Geckodriver: /usr/local/bin/Geckodriver')` you can check wich folders are in your $PATH variable with `echo $PATH`

Another thing you can try is instead of `'self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./firefox')'` you can try this `'self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()'` this worked for me.